# Multiple Borders with CSS3 with Extended Sidebar

Tags: html, css, border

I want to achieve a sidebar element with a background colour that continues down the page with the content. I have managed to do this but i would also like to add a "line" or border that is located right next to the sidebar.

If you look at this fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/MattStrange/BrM7R/

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content">This is some content</div>
<div id="sidebar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean lacinia tincidunt nisi at fermentum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean lacinia tincidunt nisi at fermentum.</div>
```

I would like a "green" background line right next to the red background sidebar positioned on the right.

How would you achieve this?

Cheers

Comment: You can try this : 

box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px green;

Comment: Hi Gilbert, i have tried using the box-shadow on the sidebar element but it doesn't continue down the page :( where exactly should i use this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#container{
    background-color:#9cc;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:500px;
}
#content {  
    width:400px;
    border-left:100px solid #c33; 
    margin-left:-100px;
    float:right;
    display:block;
}
#sidebar {
    background-color:#c33;
    width:100px;
    border-right:2px solid green;
    display:block;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
```

Comment: Hi mate, that seems to be getting there, however when the sidebar is less in height than the content area, the green line doesn't trail to the bottom. :( http://jsfiddle.net/MattStrange/BrM7R/21/

Comment: You really need this disposition? Why not make two separate container, it would be easier!